# Is there a elastic search query to get unique error log messages?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

Here is the query I have tried....
Although I have kept filter_duplicate_text as true still I get messages of the form
{"............June 3 time stamp ....REST IS SAME.............."}
I want to filter out all these duplicate messages.
Can anybody help me with this?

PS:
The second response contains timestamp in the error message itself and the message field is of type "text".How do I write a query so that it will fetch unique error messages from elastic search DB.

```
    GET log_stash_2020.06.16/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "Error"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "type": "lab_id"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "log_message": {
      "significant_text": {
        "field": "message",
        "filter_duplicate_text": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1000
}

I have added the sample log file.

{
        "_index" : "logstash_2020.06.16",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "################",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "logsource" : "router_id",
          "timestamp" : "Jun 15 20:00:00",
          "program" : "some_program",
          "host" : "#############",
          "priority" : "27",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-06-16T00:00:01.020Z",
          "type" : "lab_id",
          "pid" : "####",
          "message" : ": ############### send failed with error: ENOENT -- Item not found (No error: 0)",
          "@version" : "1"
        }
      }

{
        "_index" : "logstash_2020.06.16",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "################",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "################",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-06-16T00:00:02.274Z",
          "type" : "####",
          "tags" : [
            "_grokparsefailure"
          ],
          "message" : "################:Jun 15 20:00:18.908 EDT: mediasvr[2546]: %MEDIASVR-MEDIASVR-4-PARTITION_USAGE_ALERT : High disk usage alert : host ##### exceeded 100%  \n",
          "@version" : "1"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you add sample log lines and the output which you are getting?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have added sample responses. Please let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: ok. Can you add output which you see as duplicate? Message field has any analyser?

Comment: No message field does not have analyzer.The output for the query contains the same error message repeating many times.For example  the below message contains time stamp so for different time stamp  the message becomes unique."################:Jun 15 20:00:18.908 EDT: mediasvr[2546]: %MEDIASVR-MEDIASVR-4-PARTITION_USAGE_ALERT : High disk usage alert : host ##### exceeded 100%  \n",

Comment: Are you saying that `timestamp` causing the issue? Do you want to filter unique messages without timestamp?

Comment: Yeah the timestamp has to be ignored while filtering. Another example is : "krt_evpn_df_role_ifftlv_send ifftlv send failed with error: ENOENT -- Item not found (Unknown error: 2174873) " where only the unknown error count changes. I want elastic search to compare these strings and probably if there is 90% or more match then consider them as duplicate.

Comment: Hi please reply